# Certificado SSL

Tags: ssl, https

Resulta que compre mi Certificado SSL para mi pagina web, instale el Certificado SSL en mi servidor, todo normal hasta ahí pero despues me di cuenta de que en Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari y Opera figura como sitio seguro, pero en Firefox me dice que es un sitio no seguro.
Busque en Google este problema pero no encuentro nada al respecto.
Si alguno sabe que podria ser o por donde viene el tema e informarme lo agredeceria mucho.

El error que me da firefox es el siguiente: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
Compre mi Certificado RapidSSL RSA CA 2018 en DonWeb

Comment: Tal ves aquí tengas una solución [ssl certificate errors in firefox](https://aboutssl.org/ssl-certificate-errors-in-firefox/)
yo tuve un problema similar porque mi hosting me dijiria a el sitio sin https
tuve que hacer una redireccion desde el .htaccess

Comment: que certificado ssl compraste?

Comment: Falta mucha información en esta pregunta. ¿Donde compraste el certificado? ¿Quien es el CA? ¿Donde estas hosteando la pagina? ¿Que error de certificados aparece en firefox específicamente?

Comment: @GabrielDavid edité la publicación y agregue mas información al respecto

Comment: @Vichoko ahí deje mas información

Comment: No tengo muchas pistas la verdad. Pero si estas apurado intentaría con LetsEncrypt https://letsencrypt.org/es/ que es gratis y es un CA sabido que funciona, no estaría demás probar.

Answer (score 0):

Esto suena como un caso de certificados faltantes. Chrome generalmente descarga los certificados faltantes, mientras que Firefox no. Pero Firefox almacena en caché los certificados que encuentra en otras conexiones, por lo que funciona si el usuario visitó otros sitios antes que usaban los mismos certificados.

Comprueba tu sitio con [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) y busca problemas de certificados.

Otra de las cosas puede intentar actualizar tus certificados desde el cPanel. Sección SSL e ir al dominio en cuestión y hacer clic en Actualizar certificado. Use el botón Autocompletar por dominio o vuelva a ingresar la información de los certificados y haga clic en Instalar certificado.